# Model name 'Resource' - is it safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I checked Rails and Ruby restricted keywords, and looks like Resource as a model name should be fine. However I would like to get some confirmation from advanced Rails developer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any reason at all to assume that it could possibly be a problem or are you just being cripplingly paranoid?

Comment: Rails is using 'resources' word in routes, that's the only reason.

Answer (score 0):

I did it a quick google for reserved keywords rails and whilst I found your model name `Resource` not on any of the lists, I think it is wise not to use it.

The reason for this is that it's in the very nature of programming and frameworks, that these lists tend to change over time.

So what seems like a good naming idea now, might not be such a good idea in the future. For this reason alone I would stray away from using something that looks like it **could** be a reserved keyword.

Maybe use `namespaces`?